# Bootstrap heading font size is small in mobile devices when using rem

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my app I use Bootstrap and I set `2rem` to my h2 element and `1.7rem` to my h3 tag. Even if I adjust the browser width in my desktop (to the size of a mobile) the h1 is bigger than h3 which is what I want. But if I use the developer tools to switch to a mobile device view or view the site from my phone the h1 becomes smaller than the h3! What might be happening in here? It happened in multiple sites I created.

Example fiddle (Could not replicate the issue in the fiddle. But it's the code) : https://jsfiddle.net/gor87kg6/1/

The live site which have the issue : http://jayatours.lk/

Comment: Could you inspect the element of your H1 and see what was the current font-size of it while you are viewing it in simulated mobile screen?

Comment: The size of the h2 while in the mobile view is 2rem and h3 1.7rem...

Comment: Have you tried override it by using @media?

Comment: can u share quick snippet n jsfidder ? some sample code so i can play with it

Comment: @KaushikThanki Hi I tried to create a fiddle and replicate the issue but it won't work. The issue is only there in the real site. I added links to both.

Comment: @THpubs everything works fine here! `h1` is rendering `33.4px` from `3.4rem`and `h2` is rendering `20px` from `2rem` and `h3`is rendering `17px` from `1.7rem`,  And they show with same "size" either desktop or mobile view

Comment: @CBroe Thanks.. For `.section-title` I have set the size for 2rem. For example the `Most Popular Itinaries` title have that class. And that html tags showing up as text is a mistake... I output the code directly from the db as string... It's an easy fix. Thanks for pointing :-)

Comment: Hi @THpubs have you tried setting the viewport meta in the <head> to see if this is affecting things? i.e. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following the Bootstrap mobile first approach I noticed your website was not utilising the viewport meta.

Try adding the following to the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

**Background Information:**

> Mobile browsers render pages in a virtual "window" (the viewport), usually wider than the screen, so they don't need to squeeze every page layout into a tiny window (which would break many non-mobile-optimized sites). Users can pan and zoom to see different areas of the page.

**Viewport Information:**

> The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value device-width value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%. (There are corresponding height and device-height values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size or position based on the viewport height.)

I believe this may be the cause of your issue as the use of `rem` seems to be correctly implemented. It might be more likely down to the `dpi/ screen resolution` of the `mobile/ tablet` device itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly the problem I was having.

Answer (score 0):

`rem` is a unit relative to the font size of the base (`html`) tag. The default in browsers is usually 16px if you haven't explicitly declared it. Perhaps the mobile browser has a smaller default?

Try setting the base font size before using `rem` units:

```
html { font-size: 16px; }
```

Comment: Actually Bootstrap have already set this to `10px`. But still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue. If you still see the issue then there could be 2 ways to resolve this:
1) See that the h1 font-size is not being set again in the media query
2) Check the base font applied to the html & whether it is being reset in the media query